# db2 error using IN with CASE and subselect

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm having an issue resolving this error, but when I run the below query I get:

`SQL0115 Comparison operator IN not valid`

From what I can tell in the documentation, this is because of the sub-select within my CASE statement, but I'm not sure why. This is a query that I'm trying to move from MySQL to DB2 so I know there are going to be some issues but I'm not seeing why this would particularly be an issue.

Basically, the extension, in this case, will either be the `finallycalledpartyno` or the `callingpartyno` in the session table but I want to select either one based on which one is in my user's table.

So if a user has extension 1234, then in the session table, each record will either have `finallycalledpartyno` or `callingpartyno` as 1234 and that's what I want to use as `extension`. Is there a particular way I should go about this?

```
SELECT distinct
  case
  when callingpartyno       in  (select extension from hn.users where active = 1)
  then callingpartyno
  when finallycalledpartyno in  (select extension from hn.users where active = 1)
  then finallycalledpartyno
  end as extension
FROM
    hn.session a
    join hn.call_summary b
    on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
    where
    date(a.ts) >= curdate()
    and (
    callingpartyno in  (select extension from hn.users where active = 1)
    or  finallycalledpartyno in  (select extension from hn.users where active = 1)
    )
    group by extension
```

Sample data

```
finallycalledpartyno  |  callingpartyno  |  seconds
---------------------------------------------------
1234                        123456          20
1234                        123456          20
1234                        123456          20
123456                      1234            10
123456                      1234            10
123456                      1234            10
4321                        123456          20
4321                        123456          20
4321                        123456          20
123456                      4321            20
123456                      4321            20
123456                      4321            20
```

So now I could get 2 rows

```
Extension | secondsWhereFC  |  secondsWhereCP
---------------------------------------------
1234            60                  30
4321            60                  60
```

Comment: Why the GROUP BY?

Comment: I took some other aggregated data out of this, but I'm getting one record per user of different aggregated metrics so once all is said and done I'm grouping the data by the extension of the user

Comment: @jarlh but the other aggregations seem to work, just can't get this select to work so that's why I only included that here

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated with some sample data and a sample query result where I could get aggregated data based on where the extension is

Comment: You cannot use a subselect in the `CASE` condition.

Comment: @mustaccio so for this particular query what would be the best alternative exactly?

Comment: Outer join may be?

Comment: Does the following work for you as is?
`with query_res (finallycalledpartyno, callingpartyno, seconds) as (values
  (1234    , 123456,          20)
, (123456  , 1234  ,          10)
)
, users (extension, active) as (values
  (1234, 1)
, (4321, 1)
)
select 
  case
  when callingpartyno       in  (select extension from users where active = 1)
  then callingpartyno
  when finallycalledpartyno in  (select extension from users where active = 1)
  then finallycalledpartyno
  end as extension
from query_res`
If not, then what's your db2 version?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein that gives me comparison operator IN not valid at the moment. I'm u sing db2 for i 7.2

Comment: @mustaccio would doing a join on both fields (finallycalledpartyno and callingpartyno) to extension be about the same? It seems to return pretty much the same expected values

Comment: That did seem to return the values

Comment: @MarkBarinstein please do not answer questions in comments. They can't be formatted properly, and can go away. If you have an aswer, please type it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
with query_res (finallycalledpartyno, callingpartyno, seconds) as (values 
  (1234 , 123456, 20) 
, (123456 , 4321 , 10) 
) 
, users (extension, active) as (values 
  (1234, 1) 
, (4321, 1) 
) 
select q.*, coalesce(c.extension, f.extension) 
from query_res q 
left join (select distinct extension from users where active=1) c on c.extension=q.callingpartyno 
left join (select distinct extension from users where active=1) f on f.extension=q.finallycalledpartyno;
```